# How and in what sense can the matzoh and moror nullify the Korban Pesach?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, matzah, marror-bitter-herbs, korban-pesach

The [Oruch HaShulchan](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%94#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%98) in Simon סימן תעה quotes the Rambam (פרק שמיני דין ו:)

> ואחר כך מברך "על נטילת ידים"... **ואחר כך כורך מצה ומרור כאחת, ומטבל
> בחרוסת ומברך "ברוך... אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו על אכילת מצות ומרורים",
> ואוכלן.** ואם אכל מצה בפני עצמה ומרור בפני עצמו – מברך על זה בפני עצמו
> ועל זה בפני עצמו. ואחר כך מברך "ברוך... אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו על
> אכילת הזבח", ואוכל מבשר חגיגת ארבעה עשר תחילה. ומברך "ברוך... אשר
> קדשנו במצותיו וצונו על אכילת הפסח", ואוכל מגופו של פסח. ולא ברכת הפסח
> פוטרת של זבח, ולא ברכת הזבח פוטרת של פסח.

So one eats the matzoh and moror together without the Korban Pesach even in the times of the Beis Hamikdosh.

The  Oruch HaShluchan seeks to explain this with a Yerushalmi that seems to suggest that the matzoh and moror will מבטל=nullify the Korban Pesach.

> **סימן תעה סעיף יא**
>
> ונראה לעניות דעתי דדבריו מיוסדים על הירושלמי דפרק קמא דחלה, דגרסינן שם: הלל הזקן היה כורך שלושתן כאחת. אמר רבי יוחנן:
> חלוקים על הלל הזקן. ופריך: והא רבי יוחנן כורך מצה ומרור? ומתרץ: כאן
> בשעת המקדש, וכאן שלא בשעת המקדש. ואפילו תימר כאן וכאן בשעת המקדש,
> **שני דברים רבים על אחד ומבטלים אותו**. עד כאן לשון הירושלמי.
>
> והכי פירושו: דמקודם מתרץ **דבשעת המקדש מבטלין זה את זה, כיון דכולן מן
> התורה**. ושלא בשעת המקדש, כיון דמרור אינו מדאורייתא – אינו מבטל. וזהו
> היפך מסברת הש"ס דילן. ולזה אמר: ואפילו תימר דשניהם בשעת המקדש – דווקא
> שלושתם אסור לכרוך, דשנים רבים על אחד ומבטלין אותו. אבל שנים ביחד – אין
> האחד מבטל השני. ויפרש "על מצות ומרורים יאכלוהו" – דהמצה יוכרך עם המרור
> ולא הפסח

How and in what sense can the  matzoh and moror  nullify the Korban Pesach?

Comment: Have you seen Pesachim 115?

Comment: investigating now thanks